# Don't paste entire Column, only row based on x value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to copy the columns "Asset", "Quantity", "Market Value" and "Portfolio Weight %" and only up until the ClientStartRow & ClientEndRow

I am aware that the code I am using takes the entire row of the columns above, but when I change the `entireColumn` to `Range(ClientStartRow & ":" & ClientEndRow)` it has an error, so I am stumped on what to do next.

- The other step I would like to do is then filter the results of ClientStartRow & ClientEndRow to delete values with a string of 5 or greater. I have 0 clue how to work this out. So If you could assist with that that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Client_CRM()

Dim ClientStartRow As Long, ClientEndRow As Long
Dim Listed As Long


Set PortfolioRange = Worksheets("Client Paste").Range("A:M")
Set PPSExport = Range("A2:M2")


With Sheets("Client Paste")

Sheets("Output Sheet").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Client Paste").Activate

ClientStartRow = Worksheets("Client Paste").Range("A3").Row
ClientEndRow = Worksheets("Client Paste").Range("A:A").Find(What:="Totals", after:=.Range("A3"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Row

' Range(ClientStartRow & ":" & ClientEndRow).Select

    For Each cell In PPSExport
    
        If cell.Value = "Asset" Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("A:A")
        
        End If
        
        If cell.Value = "Quantity" Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("B:B")
        End If
        
        If cell.Value = "Market value" Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("C:C")
        End If
        
        If cell.Value = "Portfolio weight %" Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("D:D")
        End If


Next cell
 
Sheets("Output Sheet").Select

   End With
         
End Sub
```

The error at hand is that I only want the values from `ClientStartRow` and `ClientEndRow` to copy onto "Output Sheet" and not the entire column. I can't seem to work out a way to fix this issue.

Comment: What's the error and on which line does it occur?  Please update your question to show that.

Comment: @Skin added what the issue was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason

```
cell.Range(ClientStartRow & ":" & ClientEndRow).Copy
```

fails is because that line tries to specify the enitre row *relative to `cell`*.  When `cell` is not in column `A`, that extends beyond the right hand edge of the sheet, hence the error

To fix, Change

```
cell.EntireColumn.Copy
```

to

```
cell.EntireColumn.Range("A" & ClientStartRow & ":A" & ClientEndRow).Copy
```

Note:

1. Because this is relative the `cell`, the `A` specifies the first column in range `cell`, so don't update this for other columns
2. `Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("*:*")` will always paste starting at row 1 of the destination range.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much Chris. I am now trying to work out how to delete the values in this data range if they have equal or greater to 5 characters in their string... any ideas? Happy to put the ground work in as I don't want to be a help vampire, I just literally don't know where to start. :D

Comment: Glad to have helped so far.  There are lot of Q's about deleting rows, start by searching those.  The delete criteria will be `If Len(yourvalue) >= 5`

Comment: Chris, another question regarding my post, could you clarify what needs to be changed to the IF statements for the columns to get them to work further? If apply the same code ```cell.EntireColumn.Range("**A**" & ClientStartRow & ":**A**" & ClientEndRow).Copy``` the contents of cell A remain the same, however, the following 3 columns change their value. I assume this has something to do with the "B" taking a new value. How do I make it so they take the .value from the if statement as the column they copy with the ```ClientStartRow & ":" & ClientEndRow``` values?

Comment: also, I've been toying with the delete if string >=5... I decided I want to cut and paste these values onto another sheet "Fixed"

```Dim LR As Long, i As Long```
```LR = Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row```
```For i = LR To 1 Step -1```
```If Len(Range("A" & i).Value) >= 5 Then```
```Rows(i).Cut Worksheets("Fixed").Range("A:A")```
```Rows(i).Delete```
```Next i```


When I run it but it gives me a compile error: Next without for...

Without the ```Rows(i).Cut Worksheets("Fixed").Range("A:A")``` it works just doesn't cut and paste

Comment: you probably just need an [`End If`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements)